# How Do I exclude some of column values using Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a below code to pull all values from DE. Values are "," separated and they are in Subscription_lists column. Now I want to exclude some of values based on keywords.

For example in a column i have values NEWSLETTER 1, NEWSLETTER 2, CONTACT US, CONTACT THANKS, NEWSLETTER 3. I want to exclude any values which contains "Contact" word. Thus the email should not display Contact us and Contact Thanks. Any work around?

```
%%[ 
set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(Subscription_lists,",")
set @rowCount = rowCount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
set @list_name = field(@row,1)
]

%%=ProperCase(@list_name)=%%<br>
                    <!--%%[ next @i 
    endif ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use indexOf in a conditional:

E.g.

```
If indexOf(@list_name, "Contact") == 0 then
```

Full script:

```
%%[ 
set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(Subscription_lists,",")
Set @rowCount = rowCount(@rows) 

if @rowCount > 0 then 
  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
    set @list_name = field(@row,1) 
    If indexOf(@list_name, "Contact") == 0 then
  ]%%
%%=ProperCase(@list_name)=%%<br> 
%%[ endif next @i endif ]%%
```

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington